# How can one restrict the "open with" flow to multiple files?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to create a Drive app that only shows up in the "Open with" menu if *multiple* files are selected?

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to restrict it to multiple files, but to restrict it to a single file. Traditionally file managers/explorers don't implement that level of logic.